# Why is my array of pointers to objects not being assigned data from the txt file and instead has junk data

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

The Array of pointers to objects dynamically allocates a new object each time it goes through the for loop. I am reading data into the array of pointers to objects from a .txt file. Then I use the setter functions to assign data to the array. Finally I output the data using cout and the getter functions.

```
int main()
{

 const int SIZE = 22000;
 Baby* babyArray[SIZE];

 loadData(babyArray, SIZE);

 return 0;
}

void loadData(Baby* babyArray[], int SIZE)
{
    fstream inFile;
    string r;
    int re;

    inFile.open("baby_data.txt", ios::in);

for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++) 
{
    babyArray[x] = new Baby;


    inFile >> re;
    babyArray[x]->setbirthYear(re);

    inFile.ignore();

    getline(inFile, r, '\t');
    babyArray[x]->setGender(r);

    getline(inFile, r, '\t');
    babyArray[x]->setEthnicity(r);

    getline(inFile, r, '\t');
    babyArray[x]->setName(r);

    inFile.ignore();

    inFile >> re;
    babyArray[x]->setCount(re);

    inFile >> re;
    babyArray[x]->setRank(re);

    cout << babyArray[x]->getbirthYear() << endl;
    cout << babyArray[x]->getGender() << endl;
    cout << babyArray[x]->getEthnicity() << endl;
    cout << babyArray[x]->getName() << endl;
    cout << babyArray[x]->getCount() << endl;
    cout << babyArray[x]->getRank() << endl;

    }

}
```

I need the console to print out the corresponding data from the text file.

This is the output. There are not any build errors.
-858993460

-858993460
-858993460

Comment: Would you kindly provide `Baby` type definition?

Comment: For one thing, you are not checking the result of `open`. What if it doesn't find the file?

Comment: For starters, you could try printing out the values of r and re after you read them from the file, so you know whether or not it's the file IO that's going wrong. Considering you end up just seeing uninitialized ints / strings as your output, I would guess that's what's going wrong.

Comment: Avoid the use of operator new whenever you can, which is almost always. Please post a MCVE [.mcve.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve